# _snwprintf_s heap corruption error in free() call

Tags: c, pointers, winapi, heap-corruption

I am trying to use _snwprintf_s to concatenate two strings. I also want to append \r\n after each string.

So I allocate a wchar buffer initially including the \r\n and null for both strings. I try to print one after the other.

I see both strings are written. But when trying to free(wbuff), it throws me a "Heap corruption" error. I am not able to figure where I am crossing the bounds.

Where am I going wrong? Let me know. Thanks

```
int main()
{
    WCHAR* name1 = L"HelloWorld";
    WCHAR* name2 = L"GoodMorning";
    WCHAR* wbuff = NULL;
    int i = wcslen(name1) + wcslen(name2) + 6; //in words for size of buffer
    int out = 0;

    wbuff = (WCHAR*)malloc(i * sizeof(WCHAR));
    ZeroMemory(wbuff, i * sizeof(WCHAR));

    int prevLen = 0, currLen = 0;
    currLen = wcslen(name1) + 2; //in bytes

    out = _snwprintf_s(wbuff,i,currLen, L"%s\r\n", name1);

    printf("Wrote %d characters\n", out);

    prevLen = currLen;
    currLen = wcslen(name2) + 2;


    out = _snwprintf_s((wbuff+prevLen),i,currLen, L"%s\r\n", name2);

    printf("Wrote %d characters\n", out);

    printf("%S of sisze %u", wbuff, wcslen(wbuff));


    free(wbuff);

    printf("memory freed\n");       

}
```

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. However, you have **undefined behaviour** in this line: `printf("%S of sisze %u", wbuff, wcslen(wbuff));` as the `wcslen` function returns a `size_t` type - which may very well have a different size than an `int` on your platform. Use the `%zu` format specifier for `size_t` arguments (in place of `%u`). Such UB can (among other things) corrupt the stack, or even inadvertently modify the `wbuff` pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`_snwprintf_s` fills up the remaining characters in the buffer with an `fefe` marker.  I can't find this in the documentation, but I can see it in the debugger.  Hence, your second _snwprintf_s is indicating it's got `i` characters available, but your start position is `prevLen` chars into it.  Fix `i` to have the offset adjustment as well.

Instead of this:

```
out = _snwprintf_s((wbuff+prevLen),i,currLen, L"%s\r\n", name2);
```

This:

```
out = _snwprintf_s((wbuff+prevLen),i-prevLen,currLen, L"%s\r\n", name2);
```

`_snwprintf_s` will fill up the entire buffer with markers

Instead of this:

```
printf("%S of sisze %u", wbuff, wcslen(wbuff));
```

This:

```
printf("%ls of sisze %u", wbuff, (unsigned int)(wcslen(wbuff)));
```

Comment: Wow. thanks. The i-prevLen worked. made me go crazy.

Comment: Do you understand why it was a problem?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. All these documentation are so vague that it confuses novice programmers. I guess experience helps a lot in the long run

Comment: [_snwprintf_s](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/snprintf-s-snprintf-s-l-snwprintf-s-snwprintf-s-l) filling up the entire destination buffer with an `0xFE` pattern isn't part of the contract. It does so only for Debug configurations. The result is that, in a Debug configuration, buffer overruns don't go unnoticed (as the OP observed already). In a Release configuration no trailing characters beyond the final NUL character are written to the destination buffer.