# Can't use newline in OutputDebugStringW, weird behavior in DbgView

Tags: c++, windows, wchar-t

I'm using OutputDebugStringW in my application. Since WinDBG does not automatically append a newline, I had to add the `\n` in my output buffer:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
    wchar_t buff[100];
    ZeroMemory(buff, sizeof(buff));
    _snwprintf_s(buff, sizeof(buff) / sizeof(wchar_t) - 1, L"[test] %d", GetCurrentThreadId());
    buff[wcslen(buff)] = L'\n';
    OutputDebugStringW(buff);

    char buff2[100];
    ZeroMemory(buff2, sizeof(buff2));
    snprintf(buff2, sizeof(buff2), "[test2] %d", GetCurrentThreadId());
    buff2[strlen(buff2)] = '\n';
    OutputDebugStringA(buff2);
}
```

It works but DbgView prints unexpected things:

1. For OutputDebugStringA, the newline works fine
2. For OutputDebugStringW, the newline is not recognized somehow

[image]

If I don't append the newline both of them will work just fine. What is the problem here?

Comment: @KenWhite the buffer size is 100 * sizeof(wchar_t) and it's nulled before using it. And I'm only using the first 10 bytes, so there's no such thing as overwriting the NULL terminator.

Comment: @KenWhite The actual function is much more complicated. The new line has to be added at last, can't use it in the format string, updated question

Comment: My original thought was overwriting the terminator as well since this certainly looks exactly like that. I wouldn't be shocked to find that in a debug build the entire buffer is filled with a known value like 0xFD so even though it was zeroed before the call it isn't 0 after it. It's easy enough to test, either add a 0 after the `\n` or dump out the bytes of the buffer.

Comment: Turns out it's 0xfefe after the `_snwprintf_s`. Can't find it documented with a quick search, but there's this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61135165/snwprintf-s-heap-corruption-error-in-free-call 0xfe is a known value the debug heap uses to fill slack memory: https://stackoverflow.com/a/370362/920069

Comment: @RetiredNinja Interesting... The `snprintf` family is not listed under [`_CrtSetDebugFillThreshold`](https://learn.microsoft.com/is-is/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/crtsetdebugfillthreshold?view=msvc-160) but that must be it.

Comment: @dxiv Nice! I knew I'd seen that list before but couldn't remember where. `sprintf_s` also fills the slack space so it must just be missing from the list. Every other string function seems to be on it so not really unexpected.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Inedeed, that's the problem! haven't thought about that before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by Retired Ninja, _snwprintf_s fill out the buffer with another value if the program is build in DEBUG mode. In this case the wchar_t is filled with 0xFEFE:

[image]

If I compile the program in Release mode, the string will be NULL terminated.

Comment: You should *never* rely on the prior contents of the buffer, put the null terminator there explicitly.

Comment: "*in Release mode, the string will be NULL terminated*" — Except if `wcslen(buff) == 99`, to nitpick.